# Where is startTime in pyspark context?

Tags: apache-spark

In PySpark 1.3, there appears to be no [startTime](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#startTime%28%29):

```
>>> sc.startTime  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'startTime'
```

Scala has the method:

```
scala> sc.startTime
res1: Long = 1431974499272
```

[Why](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7711)?

Comment: It was never added to the python wrapper, apparently. File a bug if you really want it; or you can use `sc._jsc.startTime()` if you don't mind peeking into internals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @vanza pointed out, you can access the startTime through the jsc

```
sc._jsc.startTime()
```

I put together a quick PR https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/6275 which adds the startTime property to pyspark.